Accessing QPU / GPU cycle count registers in pi5
I'm currently working on a project involving accessing the GPU cycle counters on Pi3 and Pi4. While I've managed to find the Vedicore library for Pi3 and Pi4, I need help understanding how to access the GPU cycle count in Pi5. Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated. I've been researching various methods to directly access the QPU cycle counters, similar to the approach in Pi3 and Pi4 with the Vedicore library. I'm also looking into how to identify the relevant registers in Pi5 for measuring the GPU cycle count.
